# Sum of an array elements through while loop

Tags: scala, while-loop, sum

I tried to sum the elements of an array through while loop using the following code

```
def sum(input: Array[Int]): Int = {
  var i=0;
  while(i<input.length) {
    sum=i+input(i);
    i=i+1;
  }
  sum
}
```

however it throws the error

```
<console>:17: error: reassignment to val
  sum= (i+input(i))
     ^
<console>:21: error: missing argument list for method 
sum Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `sum _` or `sum(_)` instead of `sum`.
```

I also tried with return `sum()` but I got a different error

```
<console>:17: error: reassignment to val
   sum=i+input(i);
      ^
<console>:20: error: not enough arguments for method sum: (input: Array[Int])Int.
Unspecified value parameter input.sum()
```

How can I sum the elements of an array using while loop?

Comment: `sum` is the name of your method, it does not make sense to try to re-assign it. Maybe, you wanted to have a temporal variable where you store your sum, like `acc`? - Also, just to let you know, this code is far from being idiomatic in **Scala**, there a _"better"_ ways to accomplish that, like the `sum` method on collections, a `reduce` or plain old `recursion`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```scala
def sum(input:Array[Int]):Int = {
  var i, res = 0;
  while(i < input.length) {
  res = res + input(i); // and not res=i+input(i);
   i = i + 1;
  }
  res
}
```

This basically uses an accumulator variable `res` that accumulate the different values of the `Array`, you can't use `sum` which is the method name for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum(input: Array[Int]): Int = input.sum
```

If there is a built-in routine for something then it is best to use it. If this is just a programming exercise then you should not be using `var` and `while`, using `foldLeft` or recursive routine is a better solution.